# iOS Swift Setting View Frame Position Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, cgrect

I having two sub views inside scrollview. I need to position that both subviews programmatically. I did it correctly by writing code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Here is the code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.SelectClientDetailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 637, width: self.SelectClientDetailView.frame.size.width, height: self.SelectClientDetailView.frame.size.height)
    self.SelectClientDetailView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 837, width: self.SelectClientDetailView2.frame.size.width, height: self.SelectClientDetailView2.frame.size.height)
}
```

Its working good but when I scrolling my scrollview this both views set back to old positions. How to fix it. Its Default `y` position will be `SelectClientDetailView`:400 and `SelectClientDetailView2`: 600

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the views to the scrollView and not the view?

Comment: @7to4 ya both views are inside scrollview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to change the `frame` Y position, try this instead:

```
self.SelectClientDetailView.frame.origin.y = 637
self.SelectClientDetailView.frame.origin.y = 837
```

As already mentioned, you might need to check your *view hierarchy* to be sure you are actually adding them to the `UIScrollView` (and not elsewhere).

Comment: It work but when I scrolling my scrollview both view are back to old position

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam Where do you run the frame setting code in your question?

Comment: Inside `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam If it is inside that function (and *not* inside a closure) you can safely drop the `DispatchQueue.main.async` wrapper then — you already on the main thread :)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Auto Layout then setting frame will cause some weird effects. Auto Layout and Frames doesn't go together. You'll need to rearrange the constrains, not the frames. While using Auto Layout changing the frames will cause some weird effects and will eventually revert back to the constraints you've created in the original UIView.

Some solutions:

1. If you want to use Autolayout approach then, You need to create an outlet to each constrain just like you would to a view and change its constant when needed.
2. disable Auto Layout in that specific xib and start playing with frames.

Comment: Nice to know this :)